# How to get Printer URL from NetService

Tags: ios, swift, nsnetservice

I'm trying to fetch all the local printer by using this way;

```
let serviceBrowser = NetServiceBrowser()
serviceBrowser.delegate = self
serviceBrowser.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
serviceBrowser.searchForServices(ofType: "_ipp._tcp.", inDomain:"local.")
```

It finds all the printers which are connected but I'd like to know the urls of them for to create `UIPrinter` with URL like `UIPrinter(url: URL("urlstring"))`

```
func netServiceBrowser(_ browser: NetServiceBrowser, didFind service: NetService, moreComing: Bool) {
    print(service)
    // output: <NSNetService 0x1c0228960> local. _ipp._tcp. RICOH imagio MP C3302 [002673499B5F] -1
}
```

I don't know if using this way is a solution for to find Local/Air Printers.

Note: `UIPrinterPickerController` is not an option for resolution.

Comment: Can't you recreate the URL with something like : `ipp://hostname.local.:port/` ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to [resolve](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/netservice/1416564-resolve) the net services after you find them. Then you can do something like this to build a UIPrinter to send to AirPrint.

```
let printerPath = "\(uri)://\(host):\(port)/" + (service.textRecordField(field: "rp") ?? "")
guard let printerUrl = URL(string: printerPath)
        else { return nil }
let printer = UIPrinter(url: printerUrl)
```

- uri:  "ipp", "ipps", "lpd", "socket". You can figure out which to use by checking the type field from the NetService object.
- host: host name field from the NetService object
- port: port name field from the NetService object
- rp: The queue name (path) of the printer. You get this by decoding the 'rp' field from the NetService object's text record dictionary.

Here's my extension for getting txtRecord data from a NetService object:

```
 extension NetService {
     func textRecordField(field: String) -> String?
     {
         guard
             let data = self.txtRecordData(),
             let field = NetService.dictionary(fromTXTRecord: data)[field]
             else { return nil }

         return String(data: field, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
     } 
}
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly fine when using the Printer Simulator. However, initialising a UIPrinter from a url doesn't work for me when using tools like handyPrint or OPrint that broadcast a local printer as an AirPrint printer. For some reason I can only get those printers to connect (calling `contactPrinter`) when using the `selectedPrinter` on the `UIPrinterPickerController` after presenting it. Because I don't have a physical AirPrint printer, I don't know whether this is a bug with Apple or with handyPrint / OPrint. Have you got any experience with this Kirby Todd?

Comment: I've only tested against the simulator so far. A co-worker of mine mentioned that this technique fails on his setup (Local printer connected to Airport Time Capsule via USB). I need to get some more info from him to figure out the difference with local printers and update my code. I'll post my findings here once I get it working.